# ERROR MESSAGE PDOException: SQLSTATE[42502]

Tags: sql, drupal

I've recently updated all my modules, against my better judgement, and now I get an error message:

```
(PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'ThePINCode.image_dimensions' doesn't exist: 

SELECT * 
FROM {image_dimensions} id 
WHERE id.fid IN (:fids_0); 

Array ( [:fids_0] => 4 ) in file_entity_file_load() (line 225 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-7.23/sites/all/modules/media/file_entity/file_entity.module)
```

I am now locked out of my site.

Comment: Could you check against your database that the table `ThePINCode.image_dimensions` exists? As by the exception, there would be your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDOException: SQLSTATE\[42S02\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237619/pdoexception-sqlstate42s02)